# A question about recurrence relation with multiplying

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the recurrence relation:
$$ a_n = (a_{n-1})^{3}a_{n-2}$$

I tried guessing or changing variables but that didn't work out.
I'm also not sure if you could solve this with polynoms for homogeneous recurrence relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_{m}=0$ for some $m$ then $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq m$ (this means that $a_0=0$ or $a_1=0$).

Now assume that $a_n\not=0$ for all $n$. Then
solve the linear recurrence
$$x_n = 3x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}$$
where $x_n=\ln(|a_n|)$. Since the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-3\lambda-1=0$, has two distinct solutions, $s_1=(3+\sqrt{13})/2$, $s_2=(3-\sqrt{13})/2$, then the general solution is
$$x_n=c_1 s_1^n+c_2 s_2^n$$
where the constants $c_1$, $c_2$ have to be determined by using the initial conditions $x_0$ and $x_1$. Note that the sign of $a_n$ depends on the sign of $a_0a_1$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Removed the -1 I had put when you had the condition $a_n>0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Great answer.

Comment: No, I am putting it back. The absolute value $|a_n|$ is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Hellen I do not agree with you! $a_n$ can be negative. The sign of $a_n$ depends on the sign of  the product $a_0a_1$. Take for example the solution $-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,\dots$.

Comment: I never said $a_n$ cannot be negative. I said that the absolute value is unnecessary.

Comment: @Hellen If $a_n<0$ what does it mean $\ln(a_n)$?

Comment: Really ........

Comment: @Hellen Yes, please tell me. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @RobertZ Robert, I'm very impressed with your solution, but take issue with your initial assumption $x_n=\ln(|a_n|)$. In fact, it should be $x_n=\ln(a_n)$. Your equation for $x_n$ is perfectly valid for complex numbers. But more significantly, using your original assumption precludes getting correct answers if either or both of the initial conditions are negative, Any imaginary terms in $x_n$ will just translate to $\pm 1$ when reconstructing $a_n=e{x_n}$. I have verified this numerically.

Comment: @Cye Waldman I see you point. I assumed that the sequence $(a_n)$ is real. Then the sign of $a_n=\pm|a_n|$ can be easily determined by considering the sign of $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: @RobertZ Quite so. I've tested a generalized form, $A_n=A_{n-1}^a A_{n-1}^b$ allowing  $a,b$ to be positive or negative. However, in the latter case (negative) you'll most likely get non-integer sequences.